# pointer to a pointer in a struct

Tags: pointers, struct

I have a struct and inside it I have to pointers (each of them points to a char array). how do I create a pointer that points to one of those pointers inside the struct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C:

```
struct foo {                // a struct
  char (*a)[10], (*b)[10];  // pointers to arrays[10] of char
};

struct foo x;               // create an object
char (**p)[10];             // pointer to pointer to array[10] of char
p = &x.a;                   // point to one of the pointers inside the struct
```

Comment: can I ask another question? about EOF this time. my program works well until I press EOF (ctrl+z). the second I do that it gets stuck. the thing is it only happens with an input above a certain length, lower than that it ends the program the way it should. I know it's a very vague question but I can't figure out why it happens. any ideas?